# Magento2 : Call Block Methods from Script area of .phtml

Tags: magento2, jquery, phtml

I am able from call block function using php code from phtml like below :

```
<?php 
  $blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld');
  $myArr = $blockObj-> getTag(); 
  echo $myArr; 
?>
```

But now I got a onclick function from a checkbox as below

```
 <script>function functionSubCatCB(cb){ 
    var favorite = [];
            jQuery.each(jQuery(".SubCatCB:checked"), function(){    
                //alert("Hi Checked");
                favorite.push(jQuery(this).val());
            });
            var valCB =favorite.join("', '");


            alert(valCB);

            //var blk = "$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Inchoo\Helloworld\Block\Helloworld');$myArr = $blockObj-> getTag(".valCB."); echo $myArr; ?>";
            //alert(blk);
            //jQuery("#ShortDescription").val(<? php blk);}
  </script>
```

> Now I need to pass the value of **valCB** to the function **getTag**

I cannot do like `$block->getTag(valCB);`

**Do I have any other option to do this ???**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$myArr` returns this: `'1' => 'val1','2' => 'val2','3' => 'val3'`

So:

```
<?php $myArr = array('1' => 'val1','2' => 'val2','3' => 'val3'); ?>
<?php $code_array = json_encode($myArr); ?>

<script>
    var jarray = <?php echo $code_array; ?>;
    $.each(jarray , function(index, val) {
        alert(val) // val1, val2, val3
    });
    console.log(arraycode); //Object { 1: "val1", 2: "val2", 3: "val3" }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information, But can you tell me how to pass a value from <script> block to <php>, In the above example you have show beautifully how to pass the value from <php> to <script>, but I need it to be other way around, can you help in that ?

Comment: You need to do that with AJAX, javascript is a client side, php is in server side

Comment: Hi @Prince, I figured it out that i will require AJAX, Can you point me towards any good examples on how to do it or at least the process. It will be of great help.